# problem with php script in 1and 1 hosting

Tags: php

I have a problem.

I have wrote an upload form on my html page.  Then created an upload php file.  I added both to my webserver 1 and 1. when clicking on the script on the live webpage - it starts uploading, however the domain name/upload.php file sits there with nothing there (blank) when i check the destination folder nothing is there.

any gurus willing to help with this - i'm baffled - its my first time dabbling with php?

Comment: what does "clicking on the script" means..? this question is very vague

Comment: Can you post the source the two files?  Try adding echo "Hello"; to the top of the upload.php file to see if it does anything.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked that your `<form>` tag has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Posting your source code would help you get better answers.

Also, in upload.php, try doing `print_r($_FILES);` to output the list of files.

Answer (score 0):

Question is kind of vague, but most of the time these problems occur because of wrong folder permissions.

Try to chmod 666 on the folder you are writing to.

Comment: On 1 and 1 hosting?! Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try some more error-checking. Have a look at this IBM tutorial on [Debugging techniques for PHP programmers.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/) Some of the suggestions work only in an IDE, but there is a good deal on debugging using print statements (simple, yet effective).